# PostgreSQL: How to count requests by date if there is no request for a date in a table then 0?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table, like this:

```
| id | datetime | resource |
|:---|---------:|:--------:|
| 1  |2019-12-18| /v1      |
| 2  |2019-12-18| /v1      |
| 3  |2019-12-18| /v2      |
| 4  |2019-12-27| /v3      |
```

I need count resource per day.
And I can't understand how to build query for getting like this:

```
| id | datetime | resource | count |
|:---|---------:|:--------:|:-----:|
| 1  |2019-12-18| /v1      | 2     |
| 2  |2019-12-18| /v2      | 1     |
| 3  |2019-12-18| /v3      | 0     |
| 4  |2019-12-27| /v3      | 1     |
| 5  |2019-12-27| /v1      | 0     |
| 6  |2019-12-27| /v2      | 0     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using `CROSS JOIN` to determine cross product relation among `resource` and `datetime` columns and then `LEFT JOIN` to combine with subquery in which there are grouped `resource` and `datetime` columns containing aggregation :

```
SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY datetime, count DESC, resource) AS ID,
       q.* 
  FROM
  ( SELECT t3.datetime, t3.resource, COALESCE(t4.count,0) AS count 
      FROM
      (
       (SELECT distinct resource FROM tab) t1
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT distinct datetime FROM tab) t2 ) t3
      LEFT JOIN
     (  
      SELECT datetime, resource,count(datetime) as count
        FROM tab
       GROUP BY datetime, resource 
     ) t4
     ON t4.datetime = t3.datetime
    AND t4.resource = t3.resource
  ) q;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=25b7dd1ce13dd8b76b44ecb68cadfe41)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below. IE. `Group by` with datetime and resource then take the `count` for the  same you will get the Output . Please try this.

```
SELECT datetime, resource,count(id) AS count
    FROM public.test GROUP BY datetime,resource;
```

Output

```
datetime    resource    count
18-12-2019  /v2         1
18-12-2019  /v1         2
27-12-2019  /v3         1
```

Comment: Pranav ,I think it will not work for Id=2 , please check if I am correct..

Comment: but zero-valued counts are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows.  Then use a `left join` to bring in the original values and aggregation:

```
select row_number() over (order by r.resource, d.datetime) as seqnum,
       d.datetime, r.resource,
       count(t.id) as cnt
from (select distinct datetime from t) d cross join
     (select distinct resource from t) r left join
     t
     on d.datetime = t.datetime and
        r.resource = t.resource
group by d.datetime, r.resource
order by seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5cdf248701b0df505b9f3ef13ad9e753) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately, [this query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b7147d05263bcd9f203b4a0614c84e7b) yields unexpected resullt.

Comment: welcome but I'm sorry that the problem still [persists](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6fcbb73ffe330d8cf96006b8f407624a)